# Renumber rows after move

Tags: excel-formula

I have a spreadsheet with 25 rows of tasks. If a task becomes a hot topic I need to move or renumber the row to bring it to the top and I would like excel to renumber the rows below in ascending order. (ie. if I change 19 to number 1 the everything else would move down and renumber in ascending order).

Comment: Use the row() function to give the number and add an offset if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

So, simple example, just to demonstrate:

[image]

So, you can sort and include column A or not as you wish.

Answer (score 0):

Say our tasklist is like:

[image]

place this code in the worksheet code area:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    If Target.Column <> 1 Then Exit Sub
    Cancel = True
    Rows("1:1").Insert Shift:=xlDown
    Target.EntireRow.Copy Range("A1")
    Target.EntireRow.Delete
End Sub
```

When wife tell you she has gone into labor, double-click cell **A4** and the task list becomes:

[image]